# sort list in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary, where the key is the value of the file size in kilobytes, and the value list of files that match the size of this

```
Dictionary<long, List<FileInfo>> myDictionary=new Dictionary<long, List<FileInfo>>();
```

I need every List  in the Dictionary to check if the coincidence is not only the size but also the contents of the files (Sizes are our keys of the dictionary), and if it does not match then write them into a new List for the new key, or in the same Dictionary either new.
The contents of the file is checked by the algorithm:

```
public bool Comparison(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2)
    {
        int file1byte;
        int file2byte;
        BufferedStream fs1;
        BufferedStream fs2;

        if (f1 == f2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        fs1 = new BufferedStream(new FileStream(f1.FullName, FileMode.Open));
        fs2 = new BufferedStream(new FileStream(f2.FullName, FileMode.Open));

        if (fs1.Length != fs2.Length)
        {
            fs1.Close();
            fs2.Close();
            return false;
        }

        do
        {
            file1byte = fs1.ReadByte();
            file2byte = fs2.ReadByte();
        }
        while ((file1byte == file2byte) && (file1byte != -1));

        fs1.Close();
        fs2.Close();
        return ((file1byte - file2byte) == 0);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to try using a `Dictionary<long, HashSet<FileInfo>>` instead (and also implement your own `IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>`)

Comment: Without changing the key so that it is the actual contents of the file, it is not possible to _guarantee_ that all files for a given key are in fact identical in content. You can get close by using a long hash, e.g. MD5; the likelihood of two random files having the same MD5 hash is infinitesimal, though still non-zero. Without more details, it's impossible to even what _specific_ part of the problem you are having trouble with. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're asking.

Comment: You can change the key, I understand that one unique key can only hold one value